# Función OpenFileName en VBA de Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

Tengo el siguiente código  tiene como finalidad de que a la celda Cells(4, 14) del libro actual, se le asigne el valor de lo que hay en otro libro con nombre  Matriz de rutas criticas C&C - Del 15 al 21 de Agosto (Semana 33).xlsx, de la siguiente manera:
Cells(4, 14).Value = Workbooks.OpenFilename(ThisWorkbook.Path & "[Matriz de rutas criticas C&C - Del 15 al 21 de Agosto (Semana 33).xlsx]PANEL ACTUALIZADO!$C$7")

El error que me muestra al correr el programa es el siguiente:

No se encontró el método o el dato miembro, agradezco la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

El objeto WorkBooks no tiene un método llamado "OpenFileName", sino uno llamado "Open"; además, no olvides que la forma de extraer datos en VBA no necesariamente es igual a como se usa en las fórmulas. Intenta del siguiente modo:

```
Dim celda As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set celda = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Matriz de rutas criticas C&C - Del 15 al 21 de Agosto (Semana 33).xlsx").Sheets("PANEL ACTUALIZADO").Range("C7")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nombredelahoja").Cells(4, 14).Value = celda.Value
Workbooks("Matriz de rutas criticas C&C - Del 15 al 21 de Agosto (Semana 33).xlsx").Close
```

Solo asegúrate de que el nombre del libro y las hojas sea el correcto. Hay más formas de hacerlo pero en este momento ésta me parece la más cercana a tu intento. Saludos.